# What results to examine before "Commit" while migrating Azure VM Classic to ARM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-migrate

I'm planning to migrate an Azure VM Classic to ARM.

In the "Migrate to ARM" page on Azure Portal, i have passed the (1) validation and then completed the (2) Prepare step without problems. Now the page has two green checks and says:

```
Prepare operation completed.
Your resources will be migrated to the following resource group(s). You may wish to examine them to ensure the results are as expected.
```

The question is how to examine the results? What results to examine?
Does it mean the contents of VM? At the prepare step the VM stopped as i expected. How can i test the web applications or files inside VM while it is closed?

Are there any other checks i should do after successful Prepare and before Commit?

The VM concerns production server and we must guarantee its health and quick return to uptime before pressing "yes" and "Commit".

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you might want to double check if all the resources showing ready for the move are the ones that you expect to migrate to desired resource group for the conversion of classic to ARM.

*Saying examine them* means review the selected resources

Message: Your resources will be migrated to the following resource group(s). ***You may wish to examine them*** to ensure the results are as expected.

How can i test the web applications or files inside VM while it is closed?
You'll have to ensure the web application is working before starting the migration. Ensure all files are intact.
You'll not be able to test it while the VM is off.

Are there any other checks i should do after successful Prepare and before Commit?
None, you can commit as long as there are specific validation errors.

I would recommend going through the [Technical deep dive on platform-supported migration from classic to Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-deep-dive)

Wishing GoodLuck with the migration!

Comment: Urgent: I started migrate, the validation and prepare completed succesfully but the commit gave me the error "Template deployment failed". I opened support ticket that directs me to retry the migrate but it no longer allows me to do something. The message is now "Committing migration. This operation may take some time to complete." and not allows to retry. And now the Azure it won't let me restart the VM any more. It is failing when i try start.